# Can I make a sentence with "for example" in the middle?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

The phrase 'for example' is often used at the beginning of a sentence, but can I put it in the middle of a sentence? For instance, "Then she will be considered as a victim in, for example, a robbery event."

Can I make a sentence like this?

Comment: One of alternate mostly I would rather to use "For instance."

Answer (score 3):

That is fine.

For example,

- "Many, like Helen, **for example**, come from very poor backgrounds."
- "I can play quite a few musical instruments, **for example**, the flute, the guitar, and the piano."
- "I love old TV shows, **for example**, The Twilight Zone and Gilligan's Island."

You might find [this website](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/forexample.html) useful.

Comment: The word "like" is redundant in the sentence . Many, for example, Helen, come from very poor background.